# Comprendre « faire la synthèse d'une commande »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Dans cette phrase:

> L’étudiant sera capable de maîtriser les concepts permettant d’établir
>   un cahier de charges et faire la synthèse d’une commande en utilisant
>   les outils appropriés.

J’ai peur que je n’aie pas tout compris. Voici ce que je me demande:

- *synthèse* : S’agit-il d’un abrégé ?
- *commande* : C’est la demande que l'on fait pour acheter quelque chose ?

Je pensais que la phrase voulait dire ceci :
Les élèves apprennent à répertorier les exigences de la mise un œuvre d’un travail. Ils apprennent aussi à extraire les points-clés des souhaits qu’un client a soumis.
Prévenez-moi si j’ai manqué quelque chose.

Comment: je ne savais pas vraiment quelles étiquettes prendre. J’ai fini par choisir traduction parce que traduire, c’est en gros ce que je veux faire. Au premier coup d’oeuil, il n’y avait rien de mieux pour définir le contenu de ma question.

Comment: I think a good tag to add would be “sens,” because it isn’t really just (if at all) a translation that you seek.  Regardless, I think it’s a great (and tricky) question (much too tricky for me to do anything but comment), because to me the ‘sens’ of ‘synthèse´ here could possibly be “assemble/form/construct/create” and the sense of “commande” could be “control mechanism/command center,” with “cahier de charges” having the sense of “design/technical specifications.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Synthèse

En effet, une **synthèse** est un résumé d'un long document, qui ne comprend que les points essentiels.

**Un abrégé** ne se dit pas vraiment, on préfère dire **un résumé** (ou **une synthèse**) quand on parle d'un document. Une synthèse s'utilise beaucoup dans le monde professionnel, elle doit être précise, alors qu'un résumé est plus souvent utilisé pour l'histoire d'un film par exemple, quelque chose de plus facile à lire.

### Commande

Une commande est une demande facturée d'un client vers un vendeur. Quand on achète sur Internet, on fait une **commande**, qui contient les objets voulus, leur prix, les frais de ports, et le total. Le terme **commande** implique qu'il y ait un délai entre la demande du client, et la livraison du produit. Dans un magasin de vêtement, on va simplement acheter des vêtements, mais on fait une **commande** s'il n'y a plus de produits en stock et qu'il faut donc attendre avant d'avoir le produit.

### Usage

Cela peut s'appliquer dans l'informatique par exemple, où :

1. un client va établir un **cahier des charges** avec les besoins de l'application voulue,
2. la société de service va établir un **devis** en estimant le prix, la date de livraison, et tout ce qui est nécessaire,
3. le client, s'il accepte ce **devis**, va passer une **commande** contenant le produit décrit dans le **cahier des charges**.
4. la société de service développe puis **livre** l'application.